# Use an enum as ID in JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to create an entity like this:

```
public class Entity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private EntityId id;

    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public enum EntityId {

        A("a"),
        B("b"),
        C("c"),
        D("d");

        @Getter
        private final String id;

    }

}
```

And I have its corresponding repository:

```
public interface EntityRepository extends JpaRepository<Entity, Entity.EntityId> {
}
```

But executing `EntityRepository#findAll` throws the following:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute query; SQL [select entity0_.id as id_1_2_ from entity entity0_];

...

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query

...

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Data conversion error converting "b" [22018-200]

...

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "b"
```

I also created the corresponding `AttributeConverter<Entity.EntityId, String>`, but I don't know what else to do... FYI if I remove `Entity.EntityId#id` and use `@Enumerated(STRING)` it works perfectly, but I need that property...

UPDATE:

To clarify, the table's id is a string, so using enum's ordinal is not possible. Also, it is not possible to use enum's name since the table is populated with `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`; not `A`, `B`, `C` or `D`.

Comment: JPA would strongly prefer to work with integer IDs, and it looks like that's what your persistence unit is trying to do.  Switching over to that at the Java level will probably help (presumably, you would use your enum's `ordinal()`).  Also, note that just creating an `AttributeConverter` is not enough.  You need to annotate the entity's attribute appropriately to tell it to *use* the converter to map the attribute.

Comment: Have you tried both `@Id` *and* `@Enumerated(STRING)`?

Comment: @Enumerated(STRING) will work

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos yes, it does not work...

Comment: @SimonMartinelli it does not work since it expects the name of the enum, not the id property

Comment: @JohnBollinger if my converter is annotated with `autoApply = true`, which it is, it is not necessary to explicitly indicate te converter to use...

Comment: What is the type of the database column?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli varchar2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the id of the enum as the primary key. That's not possible.

The only thing you can do is to use the enum string value.

```
@Id
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private EntityId id;
```

The problem is that enums are singleton and immutable values. So to make your example work it would be necessary to have a setter the enum.

Comment: this seems a good explanation. Thanks!

Comment: When upgrading to spring-boot 3 / hibernate 6, this stopped working for me. I had to use `@Id private String id` instead of using the enum type wit `@Enumerated(STRING)`. Not yet sure why, but the hibernate guide doesn't explicitly say you *can* use enums as ids: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-simple

Comment: What do you mean by stop working @arian? Please create your own question instead of commenting in an answered one

Comment: I can't recall the exact error message. A quick test with hibernate 6.1.7 seems to show that it does work (again).

Comment: It works for me with Hibernate 6.2.2 unless I use it together with @BatchSize. With that combination I get `Illegal pop() with non-matching JdbcValuesSourceProcessingState"`.